# Querying Data in the View

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I got a pics table that has many tags through pic tags.

Here in the view I am bringing out all the pics

its a bit cut off

```
<% @pics.each do |i| %>
  <div class="two-col inline-element">
    <div class="col-md-12 white-container no-padding">
      <%= link_to image_tag(i.picture.re_sized.url, alt: i.title), pic_path(i) %>
      <%= i.tags.category%> #my attempt
```

I am trying to find the tags to belong to this specific pic which is bind to the i object.

I have better errors installed so when I do something like this

```
i.tags.all
```

I am getting this

```
[#<Tag id: 3, category: "Length", name: "stupid", created_at: "2014-09-12 17:18:44", updated_at: "2014-09-12 17:18:44">]
```

I want to query out the values for both category and name.

I have tried a variation of

```
i.tags.all.category
```

got

```
!! #<NoMethodError: undefined method `category' for #<Array:0x007fabc20c01a0>>
```

and

```
i.tags.all["category"]

!! #<TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer>
```

what is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `i.tags` is a collection, you cannot call `category` or `name` on it. You need to do it for each *member* of the collection.

You can do something like this in your view to display the category and name for **each** of the tags belonging to `i`:

```
<% i.tags.each do |tag| %>
  <%= tag.category %>
  <%= tag.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I am getting the values but I am getting the collection as well. `LENGTH STUPID [#<TAG ID: 3, CATEGORY: "LENGTH", NAME: "STUPID", CREATED_AT: "2014-09-12 17:18:44", UPDATED_AT: "2014-09-12 17:18:44">]` I don't want the whole collection just the values.

Comment: Make sure you *don't* do this: `<%= i.tags.each do |tag| %>` but this: `<% i.tags.each do |tag| %>`. Notice how the first one has a `<%=` tag which causes the output from the call to `each` to be printed as well.